# sitemap display in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sitemap

I am trying to make a simple sitemap. Here is my web.sitemap class.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" > 
<siteMapNode url="AnaSayfa.aspx" title="AnaSayfa"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="Alisveris.aspx" title="Alışveriş"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="Bilgisayar.aspx" title="Bilgisayar"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="CepTelefonu.aspx" title="Cep Telefonu"  description="" >
      <siteMapNode url="Modeller.aspx" title="Modeller"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="Samsung.aspx" title="Samsung"  description="">
          <siteMapNode url="GalaxyMini.aspx" title="Galaxy Mini" description="">
            <siteMapNode url="Urun1.aspx" title="İlan 1" description="" >
            </siteMapNode>
            <siteMapNode url ="" title="Ilan 2" description=""></siteMapNode>
          </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>   
</siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

And here is the aspx side:

```
 <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server"></asp:SiteMapPath>
```

When i run the code, i just see an empty white page. No error but not even a simple sitemap element. Just nothing.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, but if you're using the built in Sitemap are you sure you've defined the provider in your `web.config`?

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MyXmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyXmlSiteMapProvider"
      description="The site map provider that reads in the .sitemap XML files."
      type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      siteMapFile="my.sitemap" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Also I notice that you produce node over node, you should have a root node also as the base node for those layered elements.